# spoonacular API and django

Tags: django, database, spoonacular

i have a question. Can i add spoonacular API to my django project? I'm doing a recipe-sharing project and would really like to have a database with ingridients, so i can choose them when making new recipe.
My question is if i can have like 2 databases, if that makes sense? i would have djangos database **db.sqlite3** and **this spoonacular API**. Thanks

I looked at some youtube tutorial, but it doesnt make sense for me. I tried google it, but unfortunately didnt really catch anything.

Comment: Yes, you can. Spoonacular wouldn't be a database, it would just be you doing API calls to them. Of course (license terms allowing) you could cache some of that data in your local database.

Comment: @AKX Oh okay, so i just have to add API key to my settings.py and then make calls to them?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: @AKX okay thank you so so so much!!!